# How can I prevent my event handler from being executed on the user interface thread?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Datagridview that receives external data.

My datagridview refreshes every 10 seconds and during refreshment the table sparkles (i.e. the cells shrink and return to their original sizes).

After some research, I've read that the problem is that my event handler is running on the UI thread and I freeze that thread every time I call "Wait". I need to get all the data I need first and then initiating a thread or task to do that work.

Do you have any idea how to do this?

```
    private void dtgvPositions_DataBindingComplete(object sender, 
DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lstUID = this.ReplaceDownTheLine(this.txtUIDs.Text.Trim());
    Dictionary<string, bool> lstUIDColor = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    for (int index = 0; index < lstUID.Count; ++index)
        lstUIDColor.Add(lstUID[index], index % 2 == 0);
    this.dtgvPositions.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        foreach (string str in lstUID)
        {
            string uid = str;
            var nickNameTask = Task.Run<string>(async () => await this.GetTraderName(uid));
            nickNameTask.Wait();
            var nickName = nickNameTask.Result;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in (IEnumerable)this.dtgvPositions.Rows)
            {
                string key = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                Decimal num = 0M;
                try
                {
                    num = Decimal.Parse(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                bool flag;
                lstUIDColor.TryGetValue(key, out flag);
                row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = num >= 0M ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = flag ? FMain.COLOR_A : FMain.COLOR_B;
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: It seems that you want to asynchronously obtain the trader nickname associated with each uid. But the purpose of using asynchronous operations is to perform certain time-consuming tasks without blocking the UI thread. And asynchronous tasks usually wait for task completion through asynchronous wait operations (such as await) without blocking the UI thread. However, you are using nickNameTask.Wait() here, which may cause the UI thread to block. It is recommended to use await to wait for the result asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you're saying but what should I do? delete nickNameTask.Wait()?

Comment: You can try changing it to "var nickName = await nickNameTask;"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in another tharead, but do remember that if you want to upate anything related to controls, using `Invoke`.

```
    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // Assuming this is some action that takes time.
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => { 
                    // If there are operations related to controls, put them here.
                    txtLimit.Text = i.ToString();
                }));
            }
        });
    }
```

Or if your frameowrk supports, you can use async and await. Then you can directly operate your controls.

```
private async void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // Assuming this is some action that takes time.
        txtLimit.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering... I don't know much about thread. Where do I put your piece of code in my code?